# No funcionan (reference) en less ni fuentes con Mini Extract Plugin

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, webpack, less

tengo un problema con mi webpack. Antes utilizabamos el style-loader para cargar tanto css como less, pero éso nos agregaba muchas etiquetas style en el head de la web y era muy pesado. Con MiniCssExtractPlugin logrué que se minifiquen y se carguen donde corresponden (ruta public/default) pero me pasa que dejan de funcionar los archivos less que tienen un (reference) en sus importaciones, y todas las fuentes cargadas.

Tampoco está tomando los estilos el footer, que es el único comoponente que se crea utilizando un CreatePortal, por si sirve el dato.

Si borro todos los reference en las importacviones de los less toma los estilos generales, pero sigue sin tomar las fuentes

Dejo mi webpack y foto de mi árbol de carpetas.

```
// External modules
const path = require('path')
const {RetryChunkLoadPlugin} = require('webpack-retry-chunk-load-plugin')
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin')

// Internal modules
const Dotenv = require('dotenv-webpack')

module.exports = (env, argv) => {

  // Check if saving process ID was requested
  if (process.argv.includes('SAVEPID')) {

    savepid()

  }

  return {

    mode: argv.mode,

    devtool: argv.mode === 'development' ? 'inline-source-map' : false,

    devServer: {
      client: {
        reconnect: true,
        progress: true
      },
      historyApiFallback: true,
      hot: true,
      port: 8000,
      allowedHosts: 'all',
      devMiddleware: {
        writeToDisk: true
      },
      proxy: {
        '/': {
          target: 'http://localhost/',
          secure: false,
          changeOrigin: true
        }
      },
      headers: {
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': '*',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': '*'
      }
    },

    watchOptions: {
      ignored: ['node_modules/**']
    },

    entry: {
      scripts: ['./src/index.js']
    },

    output: {
      publicPath: 'public/default/',
      path: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist/public/default'),
      chunkFilename: 'js/chunks/[name].chunk.js?h=[contenthash]',
      filename: 'js/template.min.js'
    },

    module: {

      rules: [
        {

          test: /\.jsx?$/,

          include: [
            path.resolve(__dirname, 'src')
          ],

          exclude: [
            path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules')
          ],

          loader: 'babel-loader',

          options: {
            presets: ['@babel/preset-env', '@babel/react']
          },

          type: 'javascript/auto'
        },
        {

          test: /\.tsx?$/,

          use: 'ts-loader',

          exclude: /node_modules/

        },
        {
          test: /\.css$/,
          use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, 'css-loader']
        },
        {

          test: /\.less$/,

          use: [
            MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
            {loader: 'css-loader'},
            {
              loader: 'less-loader',
              options: {
                sourceMap: argv.mode === 'development'
              }
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          test: /\.(png|jpg|gif|svg|webp)$/,
          type: 'asset/resource',
          generator: {
            filename: 'img/build/[hash][ext][query]'
          }
        },
        {
          test: /\.(ttf|eot|woff|woff2)$/,
          type: 'asset/resource',
          generator: {
            filename: 'font/[hash][ext][query]'
          }
        }
      ]
    },

    resolve: {
      alias: {
        Assets: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist/public/default/'),
        Components: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/Components/'),
        Context: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/App.context.tsx'),
        CheckoutContext: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/Screens/Checkout/Checkout.context.jsx'),
        Dist: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist/'),
        Helpers: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/Helpers/'),
        Hooks: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/Hooks/'),
        Less: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/Less'),
        Router: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/Router'),
        Screens: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/Screens/'),
        Fonts: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist/public/default/font/'),
        Customer: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/Screens/Customer'),
        Ambassador: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/Screens/Ambassador'),
        Types: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/Types/')
      },
      extensions: ['.tsx', '.ts', '.js', '.jsx', '.less', '...']
    },

    plugins: [
      new RetryChunkLoadPlugin({
        maxRetries: 3
      }),
      new Dotenv({systemvars: true, defaults: true}),
      new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
        filename: 'css/[name].css'
      })
    ]
  }

  function savepid() {

    // Use this command to save process id 'npm start --inline --hot --define SAVEPID'

    // Require modules
    const process = require('process')
    const fs = require('fs')

    // Store Process ID
    try {

      // Store PID to be killed
      const pid = `${process.pid}`

      fs.writeFile('.process-id', pid, function (err) {

        if (err) throw err
        console.log('\x1b[91m%s\x1b[0m', 'Process Id Saved \n')

      })

    } catch (e) {

      console.log(e)

    }

  }

}
```

[image: Mi árbol de carpetas]